# Can I access my home PC from the office with SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I want to use my home pc at my office, without literally taking it to my office.
I would like to have a simpler solution than TeamViewer, cause I'm usually using Live distros at my work place, so SSH would be a great solution if it actually can do the same job as "Remote Desktop".

If that isn't possible, at least give me the commands to use terminal of my home computer from my office computer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I normally access my home PC through SSH (no GUI).

To do that, you should first config your router in order to grant SSH port forwarding. You can usually access the router configuration pages by looking up the IP of the gateway (Connection Information > Default Route). Most modern routers have presets for configuring several applications, including SSH. If you need to forward the port manually, though, set it so that any incoming connections through port 22 will be routed to the **local** IP of your home computer.

Then, you need to install the SSH deamon on your home PC:

```
sudo apt-get install SSH
```

After this, you'll be able to access from client PCs with a simple:

```
ssh user@IP
```

where IP is the IP of your home PC. You may want to make it "static", and for this I can suggest to configure a host on http://www.no-ip.com and then install `noip2` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does open up ssh on the router create some security issue?  I would like to access my pc from outside but not sure about the security issue.

Comment: You're opening a port, so think about it...
To enhance your security you may think to port-forward the default 22 to an higher and usually unused port, such as 22022 or even higher. However, strengthen your password, and take many precautions as you can!

Comment: Some people would tell you that you should forbid access with password, and allow access only with certificate. In the end a certificate is not but a huge password that you should have in the client trying to connect. Also, if you know in advance from which IP (or range of IPs) you plan to connect, it would be good to tell your router to enable access ONLY for them, which is called ACL (Access Control List)

Comment: This is a good resource https://dev.to/zduey/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-server-on-a-home-computer

Comment: @antonio.fornie It's great to have both, in case your key is stolen by whatever means, but a certificate is certainly enough for most

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a static IP, nor a public network IP, and have a personal server, you can try : https://github.com/fatedier/frp .
It can build a access node as a proxy center.
Home PC connect to the frp, and Office PC connect to the frp, the frp will transport Office PC network packages to Home PC.